# How to Get more than one Childnode innertext using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xmlnode

I am reading XML file and storing in a table, but unfortunately I am not getting all the child node innertext values, please find my xml file and csharp coding and suggest solution.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:ce="www.dummy.com" xmlns:mml="www.dummy.com">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<queries>
<query><label>1</label>Please check the first hierarchy.<page>1</page></query>
<query><label>2</label>Please check the second hierarchy.<page>12</page></query>
<query><label>3</label>Please check the third hierarchy.<page>13</page></query>
</queries>
</body>
</root>
```

Csharp Coding

```
XmlNodeList xnList2 = xml.SelectNodes("/root/body/queries");
            foreach (XmlNode xn2 in xnList2)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode childNode in xn2.ChildNodes)
                {

                    queries =xn2["query"].InnerText;
                    // text should return only first query text, but I need all the query text
                    query_string = "INSERT INTO Customer_Queries values ('"+ queries + "')";
                    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(constr);
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query_string, myConnection);
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myConnection.Close();

                }
```

I don`t know where I am doing wrong in code.

the first query text is repeatedly inserting for all the three rows

```
Please check the first hierarchy.
```

Comment: You are using `xn2["query"].InnerText;` instead of `childNode.InnerText` So you are using the same value again and again because xn2 does not change. And i would like to add that you shoudn't make any sql request without prepared statement.

Comment: "/roor/body/queries" or "/root/body/queries" ?

Comment: In your second Foreach, `xn2["query"]` refers to `<query><label>1</label>Please check the first hierarchy.<page>1</page></query>`, at every loop step. You have to use your variable childNode declared on your foreach statement

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't really be using string concatenation to create a SQL query.  Look into [parameterised SQL](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

Comment: Thanks all, its working like a charm, @PaulZahra, its root only (typo error)

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois, thanks for the catch, I want to know one thing, How I can find the value of <page> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
    XmlNodeList xnList2 = xml.SelectNodes("/roor/body/queries");
                            foreach (XmlNode xn2 in xnList2)
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode childNode in xn2.ChildNodes)
                                {

                                    queries = childNode.InnerText;
                                    // text should return only first query text, but I need all the query text
                                    query_string = "INSERT INTO Customer_Queries values (@query)";
                                    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(constr))
                                    {
                                        myConnection.Open();
                                        using(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query_string, myConnection))
                                        {
                                           myCommand.parameters.AddWithValue("@query", queries);
                                           myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        }
                                    }        
                                }
                            }
```

On your foreach statement you declare a variable `XmlNode childNode` that will refers to every node in `xn2`. So you need to use `childNode` and not `xn2` because the value of `xn2` never change. That's why you always get the same value

Comment: Which gives the following output... 1Please check the first hierarchy.1
2Please check the second hierarchy.12
3Please check the third hierarchy.13

Comment: Yes, try with childNode.Value and not childNode.InnerText.
I'm sorry i can't test it for you right now

Comment: Oddly enough .value gives nothing, i.e. it's blank

Comment: So the solution is to remove the value of the firstChild and the lastChild. It's not very clean but with that structure of xml it's the only thing that comes in my mind. You get the value of `childNode.InnerText` and then `queries.Replace(childNode.FirstChild.InnerText, string.Empty)`, and same for lastChild

Comment: childNode.RemoveChild(childNode.FirstChild); and childNode.RemoveChild(childNode.LastChild); does the trick, here's a fiddle... https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgBzmE

Comment: Thanks all for the great suggestion and explanation of each and every steps.